# GXT3 - Editable Grid: display the row to edit in a popup

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

GXT3 - Grid: Adding a column with a button to modify row in Editable Grid

In the example the line is editable automatically when line is selected.
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#Exam...oweditablegrid

I want the line to be changed when I click on the edit button that would appear in a popup.

```
TextButtonCell button = new TextButtonCell();
    button.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        Context c = event.getContext();

        Info.display("Event", "Call the popup here.");
      }
    });
    nameColumn.setCell(button);
```

There is a way do get this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have yo create a column with `TextBoxCell` which may you already created.
Then you have to disable default `onclick` editable behavior of grid.

For that as per Sencha example's file `RowEditingGridExample.java` you can override `onClick` event and prevent to fire default code.

```
public class RowEditingGridExample extends AbstractGridEditingExample {

    @Override
    protected GridEditing<Plant> createGridEditing(Grid<Plant> editableGrid) {
        return new GridRowEditing<Plant>(editableGrid){

        @Override
        protected void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And when you click on textBoxCell click handler you can start editing manually.

```
TextButtonCell button = new TextButtonCell();
button.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    Context c = event.getContext();

    //Here you can pass a new GridCell like with proper cell index and row index.

    GridCell cell = new GridCell(getRowIndex(), getCellIndex());
    editing.startEditng(cell);

  }
});
nameColumn.setCell(button);
```

If you want to appear row editor in separate popup you have to design it manually.

Comment: If you are already using `GridRowEditing`, it will already do `startEditing` automatically anywhere you click (except in the button, since that handles the click) - I think the asker wants it to *only* edit if you click the button...

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thats why I override `onclick` event and stop that default behavior.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, but why build all of that and *not* make a popup like the question asked for?

Comment: If I am not wrong he asked a question for `RowEditableGrid` and want to make just default edit effect on button click. If edit button opens a popup window there is no need to RowEditableGrid. he have to create a dialog box and create a panel and all that stuff.

Comment: Thks Mayank Pandya, how can I make a popup and call it from button click? Because I don't need th GridRowEditing, I prefer to display field in a popup, and when I modify the field value that will change the current row.